# Add list of items in QtableWidget columns

Tags: list, model-view-controller, pyqt4, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I try to insert a list of items in my QtreeWidget columns: each data is inserted in each column so there are as many item as columns.
I am using the MVC architecture but the insertion failed!

This is my view:

```
def addContact(self, list):#add contact to my QTreeWidget
    list=[] #list of contact
    items=[]; #list of item

    self.treeWidget.setColumnCount(4);

    for i in list:
        items.append(QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(list[i])); #create a QtreeWidgetItem's and append them
        items.setText(i,items[i])
        self.treeWidget.insertTopLevelItem(item[i]) #add all in my tree


class view_dialog(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
        Ui_Dialog.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def readData(self): #read data entered by user
        nom=self.nom_line.text()
        prenom=self.prenom_line.text()
        tel=self.tel_line.text()
        adresse=self.adresse_line.text()

        contact=[nom, prenom, tel, adresse]

        return contact

    def clearData(self): # clear data
       self.nom_line.clear()
       self.prenom_line.clear()
       self.tel_line.clear()
       self.adresse_line.clear()
```

this is my model:

```
class modelContact:
    def __init__(self):
        self.contact=[] #Create a list of Contact

    def AddContact(self, nom, prenom, tel, adresse):#GetContact from my QList
       self.contact.append(nom);
       self.contact.append(prenom);
       self.contact.append(tel);
       self.contact.append(adresse);
```

and this is my controller:

```
def addContactToPhoneBook(self):
    list=self.dialog.readData()
    self.window.addContact(list)
    self.dialog.clearData()
```

Someone can help me to find what is wrong?

**UDPDATE**

I changed in my view the way I add list of items to a QtreeWidget which seems more logical for me

my new view:

```
class view_window(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)


    def addContact(self, list):#add contact to my QTreeWidget
        #list=[] #list of contact
        items=[]; #list of item

        self.treeWidget.setColumnCount(4);

        for i in list:
            items.append(QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(i)); #create a QtreeWidgetItem's and append them

        for j in range(4):
            items.setText(j,items(j))
            self.treeWidget.insertTopLevelItem(items) #add all in my tree
```

But now I have a malloc_error_break to debug, and I think it's because I did not allocate my items, but in python so how can I do a QTreeWidgetItem *items= new QTreeWidgetItem() with my list of items??

Comment: `list=[]` ensures that the for-loop never executes, and no items get added. This line should be removed.

Comment: Hey thx for your response! I removed the line  list[] but I have a new problem with that line: items.append(QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(list[i])) which is normal because list[i] is not an integer! So how can I add to my list of item, my data contact list?? Or maybe there is an other way to do it?

Comment: Let me understand, in addContact, list has the form [nom, prenom, tel, adresse], which are all strings, and you'd like a single row added to the tree with this information?

Comment: Yes but I want one item in each column! A kind of list of parents to add in my tree with a single loop!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to a single row:

```
self.treeWidget.insertTopLevelItem( QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem( list ) )
```

To add 4 rows, with one datum per row, on successive columns:

```
for i in range(4):
    stlist = [""] * 4
    stlist[i] = list[i]
    self.treeWidget.insertTopLevelItem( QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem( stlist ) )
```

Comment: The latter could probably be done in one line with `insertTopLevelItems`